# Using Fastboot in Terminal Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, htc

Im trying to Unlock my Bootloader on my HTC One X+ but i always get stuck on using fastboot being unable to find my device. It gets stuck on the "fastboot oem get_identifier_token" command with < waiting for device > .

I have ADT and Fastboot on my laptop but its unable to find my device no matter how many times I try it. I have Debugging Enabled and its in Fastboot mode on my phone showing up with "Fastboot USB"

Does anyone have a solution to this or a way to get around it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I remember, fastboot requires Windows.

Comment: No you can run it in Linux and Mac now aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late in answering... ADB will work fine, but to use  fastboot you need to run commands as superuser e.g. `sudo fastboot erase cache`

Comment: +1 thanks! I had the exact same problem, can't believe I sat there 'waiting for device' and saying the magic word never crossed my mind!